# How do I import css in the npm package I created

Tags: css, reactjs, npm

I am creating my first npm package using rollup, it contains a button. I can successfully use the button in another project but the styles I created are not being applied. I'm sure I've configured something wrong but can't tell what. How can I make my css styles take effect on the button?

Currently, Im importing the css in the button file which is in its own file in the same folder as the button

```js
import React from "react";
import HomeIcon from "../icons/HomeIcon.jsx";
import LoveIcon from "../icons/LoveIcon.jsx";
import BookmarkIcon from "../icons/BookmarkIcon.jsx";
import SendIcon from "../icons/SendIcon.jsx";
import ChatIcon from "../icons/ChatIcon.jsx";
import "./Button.css";

const Button = ({
  title,
  type,
  outlined,
  theme = "light",
  onClick = () => {
    alert(
      "Add an onClick property to Button, and pass a function to customize the onClick"
    );
  },
  className,
}) => {
  const mapTypeToIcon = {
    home: (props) => <HomeIcon {...props} />,
    love: (props) => <LoveIcon {...props} />,
    bookmark: (props) => <BookmarkIcon {...props} />,
    send: (props) => <SendIcon {...props} />,
    chat: (props) => <ChatIcon {...props} />,
  };

  const mapThemeToIconColor = {
    light: "var(--accent)",
    dark: "var(--accent)",
    accent: "var(--light)",
  };

  const iconProps = { fill: mapThemeToIconColor[theme] };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={onClick}
        className={`button ${theme} outline_${outlined} ${className}`}
      >
        {title && <div>{title}</div>}
        {mapTypeToIcon[type] ? (
          <div className="button_icon">{mapTypeToIcon[type](iconProps)}</div>
        ) : !type ? null : (
          "type doesn't exist"
        )}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

This is my rollup.config.js file:

```js
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import del from "rollup-plugin-delete";
import pkg from "./package.json";
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only'

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default {
  input: pkg.source,
  output: [
    { file: pkg.main, format: "cjs" },
    { file: pkg.module, format: "esm" },
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
    }),
    del({ targets: ["dist/*"] }),
    css({ output: 'bundle.css' })
  ],
  external: Object.keys(pkg.peerDependencies || {}),
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: use [rollup-plugin-postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-postcss) package for import css